# npm - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

Windows 10 1703

Node 6.11.2

npm 5.4.0

**Everytime I try to install an npm package (ex: npm i gulp-notify), I receive the following error:**

---

> npm ERR! path
>   C:\Users\web-dev\Desktop\barber\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json
>   
>  npm ERR! code EPERM 
>  npm ERR! errno -4048 
>  npm ERR!
>   syscall unlink 
>  npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
>   unlink 'C:\Users\web-
>   
> dev\Desktop\barber\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native) 
>  npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM:
>   operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\web-dev\Desktop\barber\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json'
>   
>  npm ERR!     at Error (native) 
>  npm ERR!   stack: 'Error:
>   EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   \'C:\Users\web-dev\Desktop\barber\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json\'\n
>   at Error (native)', 
>  npm ERR!   errno: -4048, 
>  npm ERR!
>   code: 'EPERM', 
>  npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink', 
>  npm ERR!
>   path:
>   'C:\Users\web-dev\Desktop\barber\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json'
>   } 
>  npm ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator.

---

I ran cmd as administrator

I checked folder permissions

I cleared cache even though npm says it does it by itself

I changed npm prefix to C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm

Nothing helps.

Please advise.

Comment: I guess some process locks your files by accessing them (probably your code editor?). If possible, disable file locking on your OS.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding -g flag to the installation command. Please close the question.

Comment: I downgraded back to npm 5.3.0 and everything works well again. Attempted all the usual remedies, I think something in npm is locking itself out.

Comment: I thought of that as well because this stuff stopped working after node update.

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate. Same error, but likely a different cause. Downgrading to 5.3.0 fixed it for me as well. I don't have any other programs open.

Comment: After huge struggle found the solution for me .. 

"Create new folders"
mkdir E:\Buildagent\npm
mkdir E:\Buildagent\npm-cache

"move npm prefix and the cache"
robocopy c:\Users\the-build-user\AppData\Roaming\npm E:\Buildagent\npm
robocopy c:\Users\the-build-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache E:\Buildagent\npm-cache /E /MOVE

"Update the npm config for prefix and cache"
npm config set prefix E:\Buildagent\npm
npm config set cache E:\Buildagent\npm-cache

https://alastaircrabtree.com/fixing-intermittant-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-npm-install/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was trying to install packages locally instead of globally without the -g flag. Sorry about that. All is working now.